# Memcached keys are not cleared for some period after the service restarted

Tags: php, memcached

I have been using memcached for about 2 years, but this is the first time I encounter the following problem.

> Instance at Amazon Web Service, running RHEL
>   Memcached 1.4.13
>   Single memcache node (127.0.0.1)
>   PHP 5.3.10
>   PECL Memcache 3.0.5

In my application, most of my cache stores serialized PHP object. After every memcached service restart,

```
sudo service memcached restart
```

there's a period (probably a minute or so) right after the restart:

1. When I request (**get**) for a memcache key (the memcache should be empty after restart), it returns me the old value before the service restarted.
2. When I do a memcache **set** of a new key, then I request (**get**) for the same memcache key, it might return me the new key value I just previously set, but there's also a chance that it might return a value that belongs to the previous key before the service restarted.

This gives me inconsistent memcache values, undesirable situation for user-facing application.

Is this normal? Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Hmmm ... does the `service` command actually restart, or does it just queue up the restart? (I'm aware that it would *normally* restart immediately, but...)